# I have python code for a page and I want to integrate with magento

Tags: python, magento-1.9

I have designed a page using Python and I want to integrate with magento 1.9x. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Magento is php based software.You need to create the page using php.